# Calculate $\det'(A)$ using a function $f: \mathcal{M}_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathcal{M}_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> **Problem.** Let $\mathcal{M}_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ the space of square matrix of order $2$ and consider the fuction $f: \mathcal{M}_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathcal{M}_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ defined by:
>   $$A=\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d\\ \end{pmatrix} \longmapsto f(A) =\begin{pmatrix} d&-b\\-c&a\\ \end{pmatrix}.$$
>   Show that 
>   $$\det(A + H) = \det(A) + \operatorname{tr}(f(A)H) + \det(H),$$
>   and conclude that $\det$ is differentiable, with $\det'(A) = f(A)^{t}$. Note that if $\det(A) \neq 0$, then $f(A) = \det(A)A^{-1}$.

**Notation.** $f(A)^{t}$ is the transposed.

I proved that $\det(A + H) = \det(A) + \operatorname{tr}(f(A)H) + \det(H)$, but I don't know to use it for show that $\det'(A) = f(A)^{t}$. I tried to write $\det(A+H) - \det(A) = f(A)^{t} \cdot H + o(H)$ using the equality, and to show that $\displaystyle \lim_{H \to 0}\frac{o(H)}{||H||} = 0$, but I couldn't. I appreciate any hints!

Comment: try expanding $H$ into a linear combination of elementary matrices

Comment: $|\det H | \le |H_{11} H_{22}| + |H_{12}H_{21}| \le 2 \|H\|^2$. (Cf. Hadamard's inequality.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly an answer, but may illuminate slightly.

I guess I would note that the functions $h \mapsto \det(A+h E_{ij})$ are all
polynomials in $h$ and hence smooth. Hence the partial derivatives exist and are
continuous and so $\det$ is differentiable.

To find a formula, we can start with special cases.

Note that $\det(I+ t E_{ij}) = 1 + t \delta_{ij}$ and so $D \det(I) (E_{ij}) = \delta_{ij}$.

Hence $D \det (I)(H) = \sum_{ij} H_{ij} \det(I)(E_{ij}) = \operatorname{tr} H$.

Now suppose $A$ is invertible. Then $\det(A+H) = \det A \det (I+ A^{-1} H)$,
and it follows from this that
$D \det(A)(H) = (\det A )D \det(I)(A^{-1}H) = \det A \operatorname{tr} (A^{-1}H)$. Since
$A \operatorname{adj}(A) = (\det A )I$, we have
$D \det(A)(H) = \operatorname{tr}(\operatorname{adj}(A) H)$.

Since both sides of the latter formula are continuous and the invertible
matrices are dense in the space of matrices, this formula is true for all $A$.

To obtain the other representation of the derivative, we use the inner product
$\langle A , B \rangle = \operatorname{tr}(A^TB)$.
Then $D \det(A)(H) = \langle \operatorname{adj}(A)^T , H \rangle$.

Comment: Thank you! I understood your idea. So, using $\langle A, B \rangle = \operatorname{tr}(A^{T}B)$ and write $\det(A+H) - \det(H) = \operatorname{tr}(f(A)H) + \det(H)$ and take $o(H) = \det(H)$, I can also conclude the same thing, right?

Comment: @LucasCorrêa: Well, there are two different approaches. The one in the answer is a general approach that works for all dimensions. The one in the question is a nice formula for the $2 \times 2$ case, and you need to show that $\det H$ is $o(\|H\|)$. If you look at my comment to the question you can see that in fact, $\det H$ is $O(\|H\|^2)$ ('big' O). The formula in the question doesn't easily generalise to higher dimensions.

Comment: Yes, I just asked you why I wanted to use the back of the exercise. But your response was very good! In fact, you gave me a much better proof than mine to
$\det'(A)H = \det A \operatorname{tr}(A^{-1}H)$.